# Snowflake stored procedure fails from dbt

Tags: stored-procedures, dbt, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem to execute a stored procedure in Snowflake by dbt:

The description of my procedure is like: MyStoredProcedure(ARRAY, VARCHAR, VARCHAR)

So, when I want to run it, I use **array_construct** function to create the first argument, for example:
`call MyStoredProcedure(array_construct(array_construct('str_1', 'str_2')), 'schema_name', 'table_name');`

This works when I run it in Snowflake. However, when I run this from dbt it fails with this error:

> Modifying a transaction that has started at a different scope is not allowed.

Which I am sure that it is something related to invoking array_construct in this call.

I should mention that to run this from dbt I have defined a macro like this:

```
{% macro MyStoredProcedure() %}
    {% set query -%}
        CALL MyStoredProcedure(
           array_construct(array_construct('str_1', 'str_2')),
           'schema_name',
           'table_name');
    {%- endset %}

    {% do run_query(query) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And run it of course like: `dbt run-operation MyStoredProcedure`

I appreciate any tip or idea to help me with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Eventually I have solved my problem by changing the type of the ARRAY parameter to VARCHAR in the definition of the procedure, and then instead I implemented  a logic in the Javascript part to convert the parameter from VARCHAR to an ARRAY, like using 'split()' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still very much learning about snowflake but from reading [this section](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#simple-example-of-scoped-transaction-and-stored-procedure)
of the docs, it appears to me that this could just be a mechanic of your multi-scope procedure call.

From what I can see, the typical (non-dbt) way of doing this in snowflake would be:

```
begin transaction;
insert 1; 
call storedprocedure();
insert 2;
commit;
```

Maybe you can adjust your macro something like this which will overcome the scoping nesting issue since everything will be completed in one transaction?

```
{% macro MyStoredProcedure() %}

    {% set query -%}
        begin transaction;
        CALL MyStoredProcedure(
           array_construct(array_construct('str_1', 'str_2')),
           'schema_name',
           'table_name');
        commit;
    {%- endset %}

    {% do run_query(query) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Unable to test this since I can't reproduce the procedure itself.

Comment: I have tried your solution but still getting the same error. Although your suggestion make sense.

Comment: @Bardia What was the difference? Ownership? My experience since my answer has been to check:
1. Where did dbt/snowflake throw the proc? 2. Does the dbt user have ownership / privileges to run the proc? And some other things along those lines.

Comment: the only difference is I have removed "begin transaction" from your code; so it won't start a new transaction but each call should be committed.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I made it run as follow:

```
{% macro MyStoredProcedure() %}
    {% set query -%}
        CALL MyStoredProcedure(
            array_construct(array_construct('str_1', 'str_2')),
            'schema_name',
            'table_name');
        commit;
    {%- endset %}

    {% do run_query(query) %}
{% endmacro %}
```